# API Designer output mapping I can't see circle corresppndings

Tags: apiconnect

Using API Designer with API connect.
I can't see circle correspondings.
Please let me know how to do next or sample case.
I studied IBM Knowledge Center tutorial.

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMNED_5.0.0/com.ibm.apic.toolkit.doc/tutorial_apionprem_assemblyresource.html?lang=en

step no 20 I couldn't see circles.
Please check this image.

http://www.p-db-m.com/wp3/?attachment_id=726

Comment: Can you provide additional details (and maybe even screenshots) of what you're asking? Not quite sure what you're asking. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your interrest.

Answer (score 1):

I think there may be a few issues in Chrome in this area. Give it a try with Firefox or IE 11 and see what that looks like.

Comment: Thank you very match. I can get circles using FireFox.

Comment: @dataplacefujita: Can you please mark the question as answered since it seems that it solved your issue.